# ffmpeg: is it possible to have a text slideshow with a static image in background?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a simple video with ffmpeg with a single static image in background and a few text lines that change every 10 seconds like a slideshow. However I am not able to do that using ffmpeg options. Is it actually possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubStation_Alpha) or [SRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) subtitles. You can make them with [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/) or manually in a text editor. Then use the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.foo -vf subtitles=your_subtitles_file.ass -t 60 output
```

You did not mention your desired output format so I made a very generic example.